# How to upgrade from12.10 now that 13.04 is EOL?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu virtual machine (currently 12.10) to 13.04 and then eventually to 13.10. I ran the update manager and it says "The software on this computer is up to date. However, Ubuntu 13.10 is now available (you have 12.10)."

If I hit the 'upgrade...' button will it install 13. 04 or 13. 10? I know it is highly recommended that users update from version to version and I am worried if I just hit 'upgrade...' button then something might get messed up upgrading straight to 13. 10 if it skips over 13.04. Any ideas?

Comment: this is because 13.04 is EOL ([E]nd [O]f [L]ife)  you should not skip to 13.10 but if there is a workaround other than upgrading using a LiveCD, I'm not aware of it....there may be a way but wait for an answer before you skip releases

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. I will research the liveCD upgrade option.

Comment: If you want to download the liveCD for 13.04 see this page.... http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ there may be a way to do this with the update manager that I am not aware of....I will edit your title to try to get some help....

Comment: @GnUfTw the duplicate answers your question, for this case you can skip from 12.10 to 13.10....or you can wait until 14.04 and skip right to that....this will be for this series of upgrades only, after 14.04 it will go back to LTS - LTS or upgrade from one non LTS to the next, unless they change the policy(not likely, I think)  sorry I looked for a duplicate yesterday as I thought this would have come up before but could not find it....